# Why rails loads all css files even when the page does not need that particular stylesheet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

New to Rails (Have used it for 3 weeks). I have several views and their corresponding `scss` file.

For example,

**Views**

```
view1.html.erb
view2.html.erb
view3.html.erb
```

**Stylesheet**

```
view1.scss
view2.scss
view3.scss
```

When I load `view1.html` inside `<head>` of the page all three stylesheet file are been loaded (I actually do now need `view2.css` and `view3.css` at this moment).

Is there a reason behind it? Why not just load the static file the current page need? For example, only load `view1.css` in page `view1.html`.

I do know in production environment all these will be combined into one single file. Is that because all these static assets will be cached by the browser so load a single file at the first time make the subsequent visit much faster?

The reason I ask this question is because I would like only include controller specific stylesheets in the page. I have tried code below but which cause `non ppreprocess error`.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
```

I am still reading the doc at link below,

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Thanks for your time viewing the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try achieve that in this way,

If you generate a controller named Userscontroller
 Rails adds new files at `app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee` and another at `app/assets/stylesheets/users.css.scss`.
  You should put any JavaScript or CSS unique to a controller inside their respective asset files, as these files can then be loaded just for these controllers with lines such as

`<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
   or
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>`

First, disable the default loading of all stylesheets by removing any extra requires in the application.css manifest.

`*= require_tree .`

Remove this line or change to,

`* require_tree . // removed '='`

Tell Rails to compile our controller assets

By default, the asset pipeline only compiles `application.js/.css` and any files they require. Because we removed the require_tree . directive, we need to tell Rails about our controller-specific assets or they won’t get compiled.

Create a new initializer file called `config/initializers/assets.rb` and add the following (replacing the controller names with your own):

```
%w( controller_one controller_two controller_three ).each do |controller|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["#{controller}.js.coffee", "#{controller}.css.scss"]
end
```

Note: You can rename the css.scss to css also.

[Check this link for details](http://theflyingdeveloper.com/controller-specific-assets-with-rails-4/)

Comment: I will try this 2 hours later. Thanks mate.

Comment: No problem mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly declare all controllers make me feel bad, therefore, we replace @Sravan 's solution to the code below,

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["*.js.es6", "*.scss"]
```